# Apple M1 Problems with Node and Sass

Tags: npm, sass, apple-m1

i try to start a new ionic project and get the following Error

```
gyp ERR! node -v v14.20.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN AppName@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN AppName@0.0.1 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I already downgraded to Node 14 as mentioned by some others.

Is there anything else i could try?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Node Version downgrade to 12 using nvm

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem you and also i downgrade node 12

and i will face with this error:

```
Downloading and installing node v12.22.12...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.xz...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404                                                                                              

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /Users/clooner/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64/node-v12.22.12-darwin-arm64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v12.22.12/node-v12.22.12.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/Users/clooner/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12 <
./configure: line 3: exec: python: not found
nvm: install v12.22.12 failed!
```